# wp_nav_menu not working

Tags: menus, css

Im trying to do a wordpress theme. But i have an error in wp_nav_menu use. For exam;

```
 wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'header','menu_class'=>'hor-menu'));
```

and my functions.php

```
function technologynews_setup() {

    register_nav_menu('header',__('Header Menu','Technologynews'));
    register_nav_menu('footer',__('Footer Menu','Technologynews'));

}

add_action ('after_setup_theme','technologynews_setup');
```

I cant use the menu class in the wordpress menu. Help me please

Answer (score 0):

and the all codes are here

```
<!-- HORIZONTAL-MENU -->
            <div class="sticky">
                <div class="horizontal-main hor-menu clearfix ">
                    <div class="horizontal-mainwrapper container clearfix">
                        <nav class="horizontalMenu clearfix">
                        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'header','menu_class'=>'horizontalMenu',)); ?>
                            <ul class="horizontalMenu-list">
                                <li aria-haspopup="true"><a href="#" class="sub-icon active"><i class="fe fe-home"></i> Dashboard <i class="fa fa-angle-down horizontal-icon"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li aria-haspopup="true"><a href="index.html" class="active">Dashboard 01</a></li>
                                        <li aria-haspopup="true"><a href="index2.html">Dashboard 02</a></li>
                                        <li aria-haspopup="true"><a href="index5.html">Dashboard 05</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <!-- NAV END -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- Sicky-->
            <!-- HORIZONTAL-MENU END -->
```